# How to adjust Mongoose pre-save password hashing to comply with Google Javascript Style Guide Section 5.9?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, this

I am updating my Express.js Application to be fully compliant with the Google Javascript Style Guide. The pre-save method on my Mongoose.js user schema to hash passwords refers to itself using this to get the password to hash though that conflicts with section 5.9 of the Google Javascript Style Guide. How do I adjust the pre-save method to avoid using this and become compliant with section 5.9?

**Code**

```
  UserSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
    bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      this.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
```

**Google Javascript Style Guide Requirement**

> 5.9 this
>
> Only use this in class constructors and methods, or in arrow functions defined within class constructors and methods. Any other uses of this must have an explicit @this declared in the immediately-enclosing function’s JSDoc.
>
> Never use this to refer to the global object, the context of an eval, the target of an event, or unnecessarily call()ed or apply()ed functions.
>
> https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nathaniel, arrow functions don't treat `this` the same as common functions. You should always declare mongoose instance and static methods, virtuals, getters/setters, and middleware with common functions.

consider the following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const schema = new Schema({
  name: String
})

schema.pre('save', (next) => {
  console.log('arrow:', this)
  next()
})

schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log('common:', this)
  next()
})

const Test = mongoose.model('test', schema)

const test = new Test({ name: 'billy' })

test.save().then(() => {
  return mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

outputs:

```
gitter: ./nsuchy.js
arrow: {}
common: { _id: 5ac734c8b41a6b2591c30a9c, name: 'billy' }
gitter:
```

[check the 4th question down on the FAQ here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html)